# NMAKE : fatal error U1077: cl.exe and nmake.exe return code '0x2'

Tags: c++, windows, boost, cmake

I'm trying to build a c++ project using cmake and CLion but I get a few errors I can't understand:

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2019.2.5\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\Users\username\project-name\cmake-build-debug --target all_tests
Scanning dependencies of target all_tests
[  0%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/all_tests.dir/tests/all_tests.cpp.obj
all_tests.cpp
C:\PROGRA~2\Boost\include\BOOST-~1\boost/test/impl/compiler_log_formatter.ipp(64): warning C4273: 'boost::unit_test::output::compiler_log_formatter::log_start': inconsistent dll link
C:\PROGRA~2\Boost\include\BOOST-~1\boost/test/output/compiler_log_formatter.hpp(37): note: see previous definition of 'log_start'
C:\PROGRA~2\Boost\include\BOOST-~1\boost/test/impl/compiler_log_formatter.ipp(76): warning C4273: 'boost::unit_test::output::compiler_log_formatter::log_finish': inconsistent dll link
C:\PROGRA~2\Boost\include\BOOST-~1\boost/test/output/compiler_log_formatter.hpp(38): note: see previous definition of 'log_finish'
// ...
// ... many more warnings like these
// ...
C:\PROGRA~2\Boost\include\BOOST-~1\boost/test/impl/unit_test_parameters.ipp(759): warning C4273: 'boost::unit_test::runtime_config::save_pattern': inconsistent dll link
C:\PROGRA~2\Boost\include\BOOST-~1\boost/test/unit_test_parameters.hpp(93): note: see previous definition of 'save_pattern'
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~3\2017\BUILDT~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1416~1.270\bin\Hostx86\x86\cl.exe' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

The cmake file I use is the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(project_name)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

# private lib
add_library(lib INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(lib INTERFACE src/utilities)

# boost
set(BOOST_ROOT "C:\\Program Files\\Boost")
find_package(Boost CONFIG 1.71.0)
if(Boost_FOUND)
    message("FOUND")
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
endif()

SET(MAIN "...")
SET(TESTS "...")

add_executable(all_tests tests/all_tests.cpp ${MAIN} ${TESTS})
target_link_libraries(all_tests lib)
```

Please note that this same project works on my mac but when I try to build it in windows 10 it gives this error, so what's the problem here?

EDIT:

all_tests.cpp:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK

#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>

// initialization function:
bool init_unit_test() {
    return true;
}

// entry point:
int main(int argc, char* argv[], char* envp[]) {
    return boost::unit_test::unit_test_main( &init_unit_test, argc, argv );
}
```

Example test suite:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#include "../../src/path/to/header.hpp"

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE( Suite1 )

    BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( Test1 ) {
        auto res = header_class::function1();
        BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(res, expected_result);
    }

    BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( Test2 ) {
        auto res = header_class::function2();
        BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(res, expected_result);
    }

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

I'm pretty sure that the code inside test cases is correct and it's not causing the problem.

Comment: [c4273](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4273?view=vs-2019)

Comment: We need to see your code or preferably a [mcve].  Specifically, what boost header files are you including in `all_tests.cpp`.

Comment: @selbie Added test files code

Comment: can you show us the *last* compiler messages too please?  Specifically, is there an error at the end saying "treating warnings as errors"?

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica All the warnings are just like the first two and there is no "treating warnings as errors" message. Added the last one but will not add all of them unless really necessary as they are almost 500 lines long

Comment: If I correctly understand intention of the Boost headers, then `boost/test/unit_test.hpp` provides functions which are defined in the library file, but `boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp` provides the functions which can be used without the library file. Why do you mix these headers?

Comment: Thanks @Tsyvarev, removing `#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>` solved the issue. If you write it as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The headers `boost/test/unit_test.hpp` and `boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp` contains **same functionality** but for different use:

- `boost/test/unit_test.hpp` only **declares** the functions which are defined in the **library file**,
- `boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp` **defines** the functions, thus including the library file is not needed.

There is absolutely no needs to use both these headers.